# System.Reflection => Finding Custom Classes

Tags: c#

Due to unfamiliarity with System.Reflection I would like to know if there is way to return classes in a project that inherit from a certain custom class.

**Custom Class** *Just a sample class*

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent() { }
}
```

**Inherited Classes** *Again just a sample set of classes*

```
public class ParentA : Parent
{
    /*code*/
}

public class Something
{
    /*code*/
}

public class SneakyParent : Parent
{
    /*code*/
}
```

**System.Reflection Code I have Tried** *This is currently wrote in a console application but will ultimately be output to an array or list*

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Assembly assem = typeof(Parent).Assembly;
        foreach (var type in assem.GetTypes())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Parent \"{type.Name}\" found!");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

After running the code this is the output I get:

```
Parent "Parent" found!
Parent "Program" found!
Parent "ParentA" found!
Parent "Something" found!
Parent "SneakyParent" found!
```

With several more "Hmm... I wonder" attempts I still can't figure out how to return the Correct input and none the less how to return the classes. Ideally I would want the output to be...

```
Parent "Parent A" found!
Parent "SneakyParent" found!
```

...as well as return those classes into a list or array.

Comment: You want to use the [Type.IsSubclassOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: That solved the issue of finding the correct classes! Thank you very much Michael Liu!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assembly assem = typeof(Parent).Assembly;
foreach (var type in assem.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Parent))))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Parent \"{type.Name}\" found!");
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will mark as answer when I get to where I am going!